# Using the Akra-Bazzi Theorem to Prove Master's Theorem (CLRS)

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

Exercise 4.7-6 of Cormen's *Introduction to Algorithms* asks

> Use the Akra-Bazzi method to prove the continuous master theorem.

For reference, the Akra-Bazzi theorem in this textbook states that the solution of the recurrence
$$T(n)=f(n)+\sum_{i=1}^k a_i T(n/b_i) $$
is
$$T(n)=\Theta \left( n^p \left(1+ \int_1^n \frac{f(x)}{x^{p+1}} \mathrm{d}x \right) \right) $$
where $p$ is the unique solution of the equation $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i/{b_i}^p=1$.

The continuous master theorem is stated as follows.

> Theorem 4.4 (Continuous master theorem)   Let $a>0$ and $b>1$ be
> constants, and let $f(n)$ be a driving function that is defined and
> nonnegative on all sufficiently large reals. Define the algorithmic
> recurrence $T(n)$ on the positive real numbers by $$T(n)=aT(n/b)+f(n).$$ Then the asymptotic behavior of $T(n)$ can be
> characterized as follows:
>
> 1. If there exists a constant $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(n) = O(n^{\log_b a-\epsilon})$, then $T(n)=\Theta(n^{\log_b a})$.
> 2. If there exists a constant $k \geq 0$ such that $f(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a} \operatorname{lg}^k n)$, then
>    $T(n)=\Theta(n^{\log_b a} \operatorname{lg}^{k+1} n)$.
> 3. If there exists a constant $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(n) = \Omega(n^{\log_b a + \epsilon})$, and if $f(n)$ additionally satisfies
>    the regularity condition $a f(n/b) \leq c f(n)$ for some constant
>    $c<1$ and all sufficiently large $n$, then $T(n)=\Theta(f(n))$.

**My attempt:**
With the setup of the continuous master theorem, the equation for Akra-Bazzi's $p$ is $a/b^p=1$, giving $p=\log_b a$. Then I tried using the complexity given by Akra-Bazzi's theorem in each case.

1. Using the Big O bound on $f$ we can bound the integral from above by a constant multiple of the *constant* $$\zeta(1+\epsilon)=\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^{1+\epsilon}} \mathrm{d}x.$$ Ignoring the constants we get the desired complexity for this case.
2. This time the integral is asymptotically tight against the integral
   $$\int_1^n \frac{\operatorname{lg}^k x}{x}\mathrm{d}x .$$ This again gives me the complexity needed.
3. I'm stuck here. How does the asymptotic lower bound allow me to get $f(n)$ out of this expression? I was thinking integration by parts, but that didn't go anywhere.

Would appreciate review of cases 1, 2 and advice on how to do case 3 with Akra-Bazzi. Thanks.

Comment: @JeanMarie It was an error. Fixed it, thanks.

Comment: If we take $p = \alpha = \log_b a$ and $\epsilon > 0$ and substitute $f(x) = \Omega \left( x^{\alpha + \epsilon} \right)$ into the integral for $T(n)$ we get: $$ T(n) = \Theta \left(n^p + n^p \int_1^n \frac{x^{\alpha + \epsilon}}{x^{p + 1}} dx \right) $$ $$ T(n) = \Theta \left(n^p + \frac{1}{\epsilon} n^p \left(  n^{\epsilon} - 1\right) \right) $$ $$ T(n) = \Theta \left(n^p + \frac{n^{p + \epsilon} - n^p}{\epsilon} \right) = \Theta \left( n^{p + \epsilon} \right)$$ And so we conclude $T(n) = \Theta\left(f(n)\right)$ if $f(n) = \Omega \left( n^{p + \epsilon}\right)$.

Comment: @prcssngnr Since $f$ has an $\Omega$ bound on it this argument only gives an $\Omega$ result. This is not the complete solution.

Comment: It was deduced that if $f(n) =  n^{p + \epsilon} $ then $T(n) = \Theta \left( n^{p + \epsilon} \right) = \Theta (f(n))$. Since $\Omega \left( n^{p + \epsilon} \right)$ is a lower bound of $f(n)$ then if we assume $f(n)$ to be greater than this lower bound, i.e. $f(n) = n^{p + d} > n^{p + \epsilon}$ with $d > \epsilon$, we again get $T(n) = \Theta \left( n^{p + d} \right) = \Theta(f(n))$.

Comment: @prcssngnr $f(n)$ can be many other things besides a neat power function. I'm not sure how your proof applies in these cases.

Comment: Yes this is true I only considered $f(n)$ of the form $f(n) = n^{\alpha}$. I generalised a bit in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the current formulation of the Akra-Bazzi theorem is insufficient to prove the third case of the continuous master theorem. For a counterexample consider the recursion
$$T(n)=T(n/2)+2^n. $$
The third case of the continuous master theorem immediately gives the correct answer as $T(n)=\Theta(2^n).$
In the setting of the exercise we get $p=\log_2 1=0$, and Akra-Bazzi's theorem gives the complexity
$$T(n)=\Theta \left(1+\int_1^n \frac{2^x}{x} \mathrm{d}x \right) = \Theta(1+\text{Ei}(n \log (2))-\text{Ei}(\log (2)))=\Theta\left( \frac{\mathrm{e}^{n \log2}}{n \log 2}\right) =\Theta(2^n/n), $$
where I have used the [asymptotic expansion of the exponential integral function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.12#E2).

Looking at [Wikipedia's formulation of the Akra-Bazzi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method#Formulation) what appears to be missing is a "polynomial growth" condition on the driving function $f(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here I generalise what was stated in the comments. We consider the product $f(n) = n^{p + \epsilon} g(n)$ where $g(n)$ is a nonnegative function that satisfies the polynomial-growth condition, e.g.: $g(n) = n^{\alpha} \lg^{\beta} n$. Plugging into Akra-Bazzi we get: $$ T(n) = n^p + n^p \int_1^n x^{\epsilon - 1} g(x) dx $$ and after applying integration by parts a few times we get for the integral: $$ \int_1^n x^{\epsilon - 1} g(x)dx = \left[ \frac{g(x)x^{\epsilon}}{\epsilon} \right]_1^n - \left[ \frac{g'(x)x^{\epsilon}}{\epsilon} \right]_1^n + \left[ \frac{g''(x)x^{\epsilon}}{\epsilon} \right]_1^n - \int_1^n x^{\epsilon - 1} g'''(x)dx$$ Derivatives reduce the degree of a polynomial so after throwing out the lower order terms we get for the recurrence: $$ T(n) = n^p + n^p \left( \frac{g(n) n^{\epsilon}}{\epsilon} - \frac{g(1)}{\epsilon} \right) $$ $$  = \Theta \left( n^{p + \epsilon} g(n) \right) = \Theta(f(n)) $$

Comment: I don't think differentiability is given. Moreover if I recall correctly the book says the polynomial growth condition is only necessary for ignoring floors and ceilings. Finally I believe I have a counterexample, posted as a separate answer.

Comment: @user1337 I get from the book that polynomial-growth condition applies to $f(n)$ in Akra-Bazzi. This seems to imply however that $f(n)$ cannot be exponential, and the master method does not have this restriction. Your answer shows that Akra-Bazzi was inaccurate when the master theorem was not. Strange though that it's an exercise in the book if it is not possible to prove the master theorem using Akra-Bazzi.

Comment: I found this [text](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.046/fall02/handouts/akrabazzi.pdf) on the Akra-Bazzi method in which it is remarked that "if $f(n)$ grows faster than any polynomial in $n$, then $T(n) = \Theta(f(n))$". The method may be inaccurate if the polynomial growth condition is not satisfied. In your counterexample this is apparent, but since in this case $f(n) = 2^n$ is exponential we conclude by the remark that $T(n) = \Theta(f(n))$.